# Cant return an object type?

Tags: java, object, return

I have a method that should return an object type at the end. im using if statements and returning object type accordingly, but i keep getting an error saying i didnt return anything? now sure how to solve it.

```
private Door pickADoor(Door door1, Door door2, Door door3) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int numOfDoors = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;
        if (numOfDoors == 1) {
            door1.choose();
            System.out.println("The player selected door A");
            return door1;
        } else if (numOfDoors == 2) {
            door2.choose();
            System.out.println("The player selected door B");
            return door2;
        } else if (numOfDoors == 3) {
            door3.choose();
            System.out.println("The player selected door C");
            return door3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we see your door object?

Comment: @NoamHacker In this case the question can be answered without that knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You miss the else block. Although logically there shouldn't be any, the compiler cannot know that. So add something like:

```
 else {
      throw new IllegalStateException ("cannot happen");
 }
```

Edit: or simply `assert false`, as suggested below. This doesn't give explanation but here clearly is not necessary.

Comment: Or simply change `} else if (numOfDoors == 3) {` to `} else { // always 3`

Comment: `AssertionError` is more appropriate for things that never happen.

Comment: *"This doesn't give explanation but here clearly is not necessary."* You don't have to use `assert`, you can do `new AssertionError("details")`.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining because you don't cover all of the possibilities in your `if` statements, you only cover the cases where `numOfDoors` is 1,2, or 3. Maybe `nofOfDoors` can only be 1,2 or 3 but the compiler doesn't know that.

One possible fix: on your final `else`

change

```
else  if(numOfDoors == 3) {
```

to be

```
else {
```

So it covers all other values.

Comment: Thank you everyone. i have missed this simple solution but now i know for the future. this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that java thinks there could be a scenario in which `numOfDoors` could be a number other than 1, 2, or 3. Logically, however, we know that your random number will be from 1-3 inclusive, it's just java doesn't realize this.

Instead, you can change your last `else if` to this:

```
        else {
          door3.choose();

           System.out.println("The player selected door C"); 
           return door3;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in after the if block,

```
    private Door pickADoor(Door door1, Door door2, Door door3) {

    Random generator = new Random();
    int numOfDoors = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

    if (numOfDoors == 1) {
        door1.choose();

        System.out.println("The player selected door A");
        return door1;

    }

    else if (numOfDoors == 2) {
        door2.choose();

        System.out.println("The player selected door B");
        return door2;
    }

    else if (numOfDoors == 3) {
        door3.choose();

        System.out.println("The player selected door C");
        return door3;
    }
    // decide what should you do here
    throw new IllegalStateException("only 3 doors selectable");

}
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad way to deal with the situation. At the very least you should throw some kind of exception or error if you reach the point that should never be reached. (e.g.: `AssertionError`)

Comment: that is what i have written in the comment  decide what to do.. my only intention was to show that return is missing.. but still i will add the exception so that it becomes usable code

Answer (score 0):

you need `return` statement for all other scenarios. Example if  `numOfDoors`would be greater than 3 or less than 1. In this case nothing would be returned. It is inadmissible. Just add to your code

```
else return null;
```

...or default door... depend of your logic